# Why are these permissions included in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Why are these permissions included in a fresh project created with `react-native init`?
What are they needed for in a fresh project?

- receive data from Internet (some apps are completely offline)
- full network access
- draw over other apps
- prevent device from sleeping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing over apps is used for some of the debugging functionality (red error screen. warning popups).  Everything else is added because Facebook feels that you'll likely use it.  Remove it if you don't need it.  You can remove the draw over other apps as well if you don't mind some debugging functionality breaking.

Comment: debug popups will only be shown when the app is in foreground, there's no need to draw over **other** apps? I don't think the permission is necessary to draw over your own app (it's just rendering a different view).

Comment: @Avery235 It all depends on how you do it.  The way they do it (or at least did it at one time) required it.  But feel free to yank it and see what breaks, it may be nothing now.